# mysql query to split one column into many separate columns based on id

Tags: mysql

I have a single table as below:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+
|  ID       | Name      | Format |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 1         | Rama      | Text   |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 2         | Sita      | Text   |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 1         | Raja      | Text   |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 2         | Bheem      | Text   |
+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

I want below output from above table:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  ID_1     | ID_2      |
+-----------+-----------+
| Rama      | Sita      |
+-----------+-----------+
| Raja      | Bheem     |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Can anyone give me mysql query to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you know which id 1 to pair with which id 2 record? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have written 2 separate query to extract the data. Like  select Name as ID_1 from table1 where ID=1;   Is it possible to get single query for this or do i need to join 2 subqueries.

Comment: You have not answered my question.

Comment: no need to pair.. I just need two columns, one for Id 1 and another for id 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT  ID,
        MAX(IF(`ID` = 1, Name, NULL)) ID_1,
        MAX(IF(`ID` = 2, Name, NULL)) ID_2
FROM    Table
GROUP   BY ID
```

Follow this fiddle code which is similar to your requirement.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70129/13

Comment: Why do you use the max()?

Comment: @Shadow : Just try it out without `max`, then you will be able to understand why did he use `max()`